# data range changes when warping

Tags: gdalwarp

When the source band having pixel values in the range of 52 and 207 is warped using the following command:

```
gdal_warp -t_srs wgs84 -r near in_file out_file
```

The resulted band has the pixel values in the range of 0 and 207. How can I make the data range unchanged during warp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your zero values occur where you have no data (warping distorts the images and an output image must be rectangular, hence the noData pixels). You can force the output NoData value using

-dstnodata

In your case, -dstnodata None would create undefined NoData that will not be included in the range.

Answer (score 1):

With a version of GDAL 1.10.1 or any other below 2.0, you need to specify a numeric value for NoData.

`None` did not work for me.

For instance:

`-dstnodata -999`

You can run `gdalinfo -stats yourfile` first in order to know whether your image has a determined value for NoData values.

Comment: hi, i followed your suggestion, but the range in my output raster still has the same amount of difference from the source. is this an unavoidable result of the resampling?